# Entity Framework 4 - Database First

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have deleted a column from a table in SQL Server and then I went on to do the same on EF Diagram by right click on the column and then choosing 'Delete from model'.

All of my entities went missing then!

Is there any reason for this and what can I do to restore ..

Thanks.

Comment: delete the particular modified table from designer then right click on designer and select `update model from database` and select the updated table. It will update the model according to modified table schema.

Comment: Thank you this helped but a lot of 'regressions' then everywhere; since I customized my navigation properties with proper expressive names...

I think it is disgraceful of the EF not to have the alternative way of simply deleting the column or refreshing the table to make both sql and ef match.